# awk- Manipulating a file by comparing fields

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

I have 2 files as follows:

**section_ne.csv**

```
NE_section,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
D,NE Name,IP Address,Site Name,en Product Legacy Code,en Product Legacy Revision,Product Model,NE Status,company Serial Number,company SW Major Release,company SW Minor Release,company SW Patch Release,Manufacturing Date,Installation Date ,Into Service Date ,Licensed System ID,Licensed Key,Decommissioning Date,Description,,,,,
X,ts,1.1.1.26,,,,Linux,,,9.6.02,356349,,,,,,,,A,,,,,
X,ts_I,1.1.1.26,,,,Linux,,,9.6.02,356272,,,,,,,,I,,,,,
X,ts_O,1.1.1.26,,,,Linux,,,9.6.01,348219,,,,,,,,O,,,,,
X,ts_S,1.1.1.26,,,,Linux,,,9.6.02,356272,,,,,,,,S,,,,,
X,1.1.88.83,1.1.88.83,,,,O-M,,,4.8,a7gpaa48.766,,,,,,,,,,,,,
X,is180,10.5.5.180,,,,N-D,,,5.2,a6gpaa52.604,,,,,,,,,,,,,
X,is171,10.5.5.171,,,,N-F,,,5.4,a6gpaa54.431,,,,,,,,,,,,,
X,is174,10.5.5.174,,,,N-F,,,5.4,a6gpaa54.431,,,,,,,,,,,,,
X,Detected_at_10.5.5.106,10.5.5.106,,,,N-B,,,5.5,a6gpaa55.568,,,,,,,,,,,,,
X,is112,10.5.5.112,,,,N-A,,,5.5,a6gpaa55.574,,,,,,,,,,,,,
X,is107,10.5.5.107,,,,N-A,,,5.6,a6gpaa56.561,,,,,,,,,,,,,
X,172.29.7.227,172.29.7.227,,,,N-D,,,5.6,a6gpaa56.175,,,,,,,,,,,,,
X,Detected_at_10.5.5.121,10.5.5.121,,,,N-A,,,5.6,a6gpaa56.462,,,,,,,,,,,,,
X,is172,10.5.5.172,,,,N-F,,,5.6,a6gpaa56.561,,,,,,,,,,,,,
X,is179,10.5.5.179,,,,N-D,,,5.6,a6gpaa56.561,,,,,,,,,,,,,
X,is181,10.5.5.181,,,,N-D,,,5.6,a6gpaa56.453,,,,,,,,,,,,,
X,eyup,10.5.5.91,,,,C-A,,,5.6,a6gpaa56.557,,,,,,,,,,,,,
...
```

**lookup.csv**

```
Patch_release,Build
5.7.02,
5.7.01e,57.345
5.7.01,57.324
5.7.00c,57.161
5.7.00a,57.160
5.7,57.145
5.6.02d,
5.6.02b,56.574
5.6.02a,56.562
5.6.02,56.561
5.6.01j,56.463
5.6.01g,56.476
5.6.01f,
5.6.01e,56.488
5.6.01c,56.462
5.6.01b,56.453
5.6.01a,56.452
5.6.01,56.439
5.6.00a,56.157
5.6,56.153
5.5.02h,
5.5.02g,55.598
...
```

I would like do following:

- Compare these files with awk
- If the 11th field (company SW Minor Release) of section_ne.csv contains any of the Build listed in lookup.csv (located in 2nd column), fetch the matching Patch_release value from lookup.csv table and update section_ne.csv file
- put this Patch_release value to the 12th field of section_ne.csv (company SW Patch Release).

For example:

```
NE_section,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
D,NE Name,IP Address,Site Name,en Product Legacy Code,en Product Legacy Revision,Product Model,NE Status,company Serial Number,company SW Major Release,company SW Minor Release,company SW Patch Release,Manufacturing Date,Installation Date ,Into Service Date ,Licensed System ID,Licensed Key,Decommissioning Date,Description,,,,,
...
    X,is107,10.5.5.107,,,,N-A,,,5.6,a6gpaa56.561,,,,,,,,,,,,,
...
```

This entry will be matched with following entry in lookup.csv file:

```
5.6.02,56.561
```

And then the related entry in section_ne.csv file will be updated as following:

```
X,is107,10.5.5.107,,,,N-A,,,5.6,a6gpaa56.561,5.6.02,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Comment: awk is not a CSV parser, imagine an input like this : `foo,"bar,base", qux`

Comment: It would be easier if we could change the "contains" test to an "equals" test: is there a way to strip off the "non-build" characters from the 11th field?

Answer (score 0):

Is that your idea? A quick dirty example:

```
$ sort -V -t , -k 1 lookup.csv > lookup_sorted.csv 
$ sort -V -t , -k 10 section_ne.csv > section_ne_sorted.csv 
$ join -1 10 -2 1 -t , section_ne_sorted.csv lookup_sorted.csv 
5.6,X,172.29.7.227,172.29.7.227,,,,N-D,,,a6gpaa56.175,,,,,,,,,,,,,,56.153
5.6,X,is181,10.5.5.181,,,,N-D,,,a6gpaa56.453,,,,,,,,,,,,,,56.153
5.6,X,Detected_at_10.5.5.121,10.5.5.121,,,,N-A,,,a6gpaa56.462,,,,,,,,,,,,,,56.153
5.6,X,eyup,10.5.5.91,,,,C-A,,,a6gpaa56.557,,,,,,,,,,,,,,56.153
5.6,X,is107,10.5.5.107,,,,N-A,,,a6gpaa56.561,,,,,,,,,,,,,,56.153
5.6,X,is172,10.5.5.172,,,,N-F,,,a6gpaa56.561,,,,,,,,,,,,,,56.153
5.6,X,is179,10.5.5.179,,,,N-D,,,a6gpaa56.561,,,,,,,,,,,,,,56.153
join: file 2 is not in sorted order
join: file 1 is not in sorted order
```

Comment: this does not provide the result file I need.

Answer (score -1):

I would use join command

> Join · Description For each pair of input lines with identical join
>   fields, write a line to standard output. The default join field is the
>   first, delimited by whitespace. When FILE1 or FILE2 (not both) is -,
>   read standard input.

[join](https://linux.die.net/man/1/join)

In the following site[click here](https://shapeshed.com/unix-join/)
 you can find an example with csv files.

Comment: How would you _update_ the `section_ne.csv` file using `join`?